# ZipArchive::addEmptyDir is not creating empty dir in ubuntu 3.15 & PHP 5.3.10

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to add empty director to archive, by using the following code in ubuntu3.15 running PHP 5.3.10. But it is creating a zip without empty directory in it. Any idea what's wrong in the code?

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "/var/www/enteliweb/website/public/test.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) 
  {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
  }

if($zip->addEmptyDir('newDirectory')) 
  {
    echo 'Created a new root directory';
  } else {
    echo 'Could not create the directory';
  }
$zip->close();
```

Comment: What tool are you checking the zip with? Maybe it doesn't recognise the way the empty directory was recorded?

Comment: I'm just using File Roller (Archive manager for GNOME)

Comment: OK, so have you tried listing the contents with a different tool? e.g. the command-line `unzip` command, or using PHP to read back the created file? Just to rule out possibilities / gain extra information.

Comment: When I open the zip I can't see the list of empty folders using UI tool, But when I unzip using unzip command empty folder shows up.

Comment: Aha, so now we have a different question: why doesn't the "File Roller" program show the empty directory? Is it a bug/limitation of that tool, which you took for granted as showing "the truth"?